# Close a sidebar when I click outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am trying to close a sidebar when I click outside of it.
I have added a condition to only close it if it is open (`nav_active`), but I am missing something.
The expected behavior would be to display the alert when I click inside or outside the red box.

**edit after solution**
I just realized that the first click will be on the outside, so when I will remove the active class, the slider will never be shown

```js
"use strict";

var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');

burger.addEventListener('click', function () {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
  });

if (nav.classList.contains("nav_active")) { 

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {   
      
    nav.classList.remove('nav_active');
      });
    }
```

```css
.nav_home, .nav_links, .nav_buttons, .nav_list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.burger {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  margin: auto 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}


.nav_list a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}


  .nav_links {
    display: block;
    z-index: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0rem;
    width: 80%;
    margin-right: 0.1rem;
    border-left: 0.1rem solid;
    background: red;
  }

  .nav_item {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav_list {
    display: block;
    a {
      display: block;
    }
    span {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  
  .nav_active {
  background: blue;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">

  <div class="header container">


    <div class="nav_links">

      <h5 class="nav_list">
        <span class="noselect">⁄</span>
      </h5>

      <div class="nav_buttons">

        <h5 class="theme-label"></h5>

      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="burger"></div>

  </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second event listener never gets added because at function call `.nav_links` has no class `.nav_active`. So you have to move the `if (nav.classList.contains("nav_active"))` inside the handler function of that listener.

**Working example:**
(for demonstration i changed the background to green when active)

```js
"use strict";

var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');

var navSlide = function() {
  burger.addEventListener('click', function() {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
    console.log("Clicked on Burger");
  });
  window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {   // i exchanged
    if (nav.classList.contains("nav_active")) {    // these 2 lines
      if (nav.contains(e.target)) {
        console.log("Clicked in Box");
      }
      else {
        console.log("Clicked outside Box");
      }
    }                                              // and
  });                                              // these
};

navSlide();
```

```css
.nav_home,
.nav_links,
.nav_buttons,
.nav_list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.burger {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  margin: auto 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}

.nav_list a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.nav_links {
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0rem;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 0.1rem;
  border-left: 0.1rem solid;
  background: red;
}

.nav_item {
  display: block;
}

.nav_list {
  display: block;
  a {
    display: block;
  }
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}

.nav_active {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="header container">

    <div class="nav_links">
      <h5 class="nav_list">
        <span class="noselect">⁄</span>
      </h5>

      <div class="nav_buttons">
        <h5 class="theme-label"></h5>
        <input class="themeSwitch" type="checkbox" id="switch" name="theme" />
        <label class="toggle" for="switch"></label>
        <label class="switch" for="switch"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="burger"></div>
  </div>

</header>
```

---

But i think when you just want to toggle a menu you could simply procede all with one event listener (and its handler). So you just have to handle two cases: if the click was on the `burger` or outside the `nav` (and the burger). The third case (the last `else`) is just for demonstration.

**Working example:**
(i omitted the `navSlide()` function)

```js
"use strict";

var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');

window.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('burger')) {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
    console.log("Clicked on Burger");
  }
  else if (!nav.contains(e.target)) {
    nav.classList.remove('nav_active');
    console.log("Clicked outside Box");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Clicked in Box");
  }
});
```

```css
.nav_home,
.nav_links,
.nav_buttons,
.nav_list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.burger {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  margin: auto 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}

.nav_list a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.nav_links {
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0rem;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 0.1rem;
  border-left: 0.1rem solid;
  background: red;
}

.nav_item {
  display: block;
}

.nav_list {
  display: block;
  a {
    display: block;
  }
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}

.nav_links.nav_active {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="header container">

    <div class="nav_links">
      <h5 class="nav_list">
        <span class="noselect">⁄</span>
      </h5>

      <div class="nav_buttons">
        <h5 class="theme-label"></h5>
        <input class="themeSwitch" type="checkbox" id="switch" name="theme" />
        <label class="toggle" for="switch"></label>
        <label class="switch" for="switch"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="burger"></div>
  </div>

</header>
```

---

If you want the second event listener only to be added if the menu is open (`nav.classList.contains("nav_active")`) and else removed, you have to nest it into the handler of the first listener (the anonymous function). You have to define the second handler as a separate function (here `checkClickLocation()`) because `removeEventListener()` needs the function reference (here `checkClickLocation`) as parameter to stop it.

**Working example:**

```js
"use strict";

var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');

function checkClickLocation(e) {
  if (!nav.contains(e.target)) {
    nav.classList.remove('nav_active');
    window.removeEventListener('click', checkClickLocation);
    console.log("Clicked outside Box");
  }
  else {
    console.log("Clicked in Box");
  }
}

burger.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation()
  nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
  if (nav.classList.contains("nav_active")) {
    window.addEventListener('click', checkClickLocation);
  }
  else {
    window.removeEventListener('click', checkClickLocation);
  }
  console.log("Clicked on Burger");
});
```

```css
.nav_home,
.nav_links,
.nav_buttons,
.nav_list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.burger {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  margin: auto 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}

.nav_list a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.nav_links {
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0rem;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 0.1rem;
  border-left: 0.1rem solid;
  background: red;
}

.nav_item {
  display: block;
}

.nav_list {
  display: block;
  a {
    display: block;
  }
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}

.nav_active {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="header container">

    <div class="nav_links">
      <h5 class="nav_list">
        <span class="noselect">⁄</span>
      </h5>

      <div class="nav_buttons">
        <h5 class="theme-label"></h5>
        <input class="themeSwitch" type="checkbox" id="switch" name="theme" />
        <label class="toggle" for="switch"></label>
        <label class="switch" for="switch"></label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="burger"></div>
  </div>

</header>
```

Comment: Would like to know, why to put the `addEventListener` codes in side a function and then call it. We can put it outside without any function I guess?

Comment: Yes, i would also like to know that. Maybe @smugdessert knows...

Comment: i would also like to know that

Comment: the only thing I want to ask is how could I have the `window.addEventListener` trigger only when `nav_active` is added. I don't want to always check where I click if I know the slider is closed.

Comment: thank you, I just got into learning JS and I appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

You just needed to move the code into your listener - and I reformatted the way you assign the variable to the function. Finally, I removed the `window` event listener on the toggle off.

```js
"use strict";

var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
var nav = document.querySelector('.nav_links');

const navSlide = () => {
  burger.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
    nav.classList.toggle('nav_active');
    if (nav.classList.contains("nav_active")) {
      window.addEventListener('click', captureClick);
      console.log("ADDED WINDOW LISTENER")
    } else {
      // remove the window event listener
      window.removeEventListener('click', captureClick);
      console.log("REMOVED WINDOW LISTENER")
    }
  });
};

const captureClick = (e) => {
  if (nav.contains(e.target)) {
    alert("Clicked in Box");
  } else {
    alert("Clicked outside Box");
  }
}
navSlide();
```

```css
.nav_home,
.nav_links,
.nav_buttons,
.nav_list {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.burger {
  width: 2.4rem;
  height: 2.4rem;
  margin: auto 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: black;
}

.nav_list a:hover {
  text-decoration: line-through !important;
}

.nav_links {
  display: block;
  z-index: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0rem;
  width: 80%;
  margin-right: 0.1rem;
  border-left: 0.1rem solid;
  background: red;
}

.nav_item {
  display: block;
}

.nav_list {
  display: block;
  a {
    display: block;
  }
  span {
    display: none;
  }
}

.nav_active {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="header container">
    <div class="nav_links">
      <h5 class="nav_list">
        <span class="noselect">⁄</span>
      </h5>
      <div class="nav_buttons">
        <h5 class="theme-label"></h5>
        <input class="themeSwitch" type="checkbox" id="switch" name="theme" />
        <label class="toggle" for="switch"></label>
        <label class="switch" for="switch"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="burger"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Once you added an event listener it will remain added even after the toggle classlist removes `nav_active` class. so this code `window.addEventListener('click'` will always remain active. I guess this is not the right solution?

Comment: Excellent point and thanks @RajdeepDebnath - code updated